# A symbol used in civil engineering

Tags: symbols

How to make a symbol like this? Due to the reputation limit, I can't upload an image. So I decribe the symbol by word, I hope you can understand it. My symbol is:

> a phi with an underscore. phi is `\niphi`.

Comment: does the symbol have a standard meaning? If yes, it may help if you give that meaning if you cannot find a link on the internet showing that symbol.

Comment: You can upload the image to imgur.com and add a link to it. Also, have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: for civil engineer, it means the second grade steel bar.

Comment: \underline{\niphi}

is that what you mean or 

    \niphi_{\_}

?

Comment: sorry, just read your answer. no, it is not what i want because there is some space between phi and underline. please read the below Alan Munn's answer. it is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps this does what you want. (Adapted from the Comprehensive Symbols Guide (available in your TeX Distribution.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek,slashed}
\newcommand*{\ulphi}{{%
\declareslashed{}{-}{0}{-.62}{\upphi}\slashed{\upphi}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\ulphi
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

A similar question has been asked on the site with some more general solutions:

- [How to get the Reinforced symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88718/2693)

Comment: thanks a lot. this is exactly what i want. you are a really superman. you also answered my last question. you mentioned "Comprehensive Symbols Guide". where can i find it? i also have another symbol which is very similar to this one. the only difference is that it has two vertical lines. can you show me how to do it? thanks.

Comment: The Comprehensive Symbols Guide is part of the standard TeX documentation.  If you use the command line: `texdoc symbols` should find it.  If you look at package documentation from within your editor, then enter `symbols` as the package name.

Comment: could you please help me make the symbol i mentioned in the above comment?

Comment: could you please help me make this symbol? [1]: http://i.imgur.com/qUVlE.jpg

Comment: @AlanMunn -- the requested symbols are indeed the same as for the question you cited.  (it may or may not be a coincidence that the posters of both questions are located in china.)  in any event, i've tried to locate the symbols in unicode, and failed.  i couldn't find any on-line reference (other than this forum) in which the symbols are shown as individual symbols, not as part of a structural drawing.  if such a reference can be found, the symbols can be submitted for consideration by unicode, and i'm willing to do that.  but i need an example in a published document.

Answer (score 3):

This link has probably been posted in response to various other "How do I get xxx symbol" questions, but anyway here it is again:

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Draw your symbol there, and the system will try to identify it (together with the LaTeX package and command that produces it).

Comment: the link is cool although i can't find my symbol there. it is an easy way to find some symbol in TEX. thank you.