# How to get the Reinforced symbols?

Tags: symbols

Recently,  An  asistant asked me a question that how to get the Reinforced symbols?
[image]

I can not  find it  in  [sym­bols-a4.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Maybe  it is not  universal notation.

Comment: It would help if you knew the names of these symbols. Where are they used?

Comment: In chinese building engineering, reinforcing steel symbols is used to design the building.

Answer (score 8):

The creation of such symbols are fairly straight forward if you follow the "`\ooalign` tutorial| in [`\subseteq` + `\circ` as a single symbol (“open subset”)](http://goo.gl/pkzNr):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\newcommand{\symbolA}{{%
  \ooalign{\raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.9}{o}}\cr\hss\rule{.4pt}{1.5ex}\hss}}}
\newcommand{\symbolB}{{%
  \ooalign{\hss\raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.9}{o}}\hss\cr\hss\rule{.4pt}{1.5ex}\hss\cr\rule{1.5ex}{.4pt}}}}
\newcommand{\symbolC}{{%
  \ooalign{\hss\raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.9}{o}}\hss\cr\hss\rule{.4pt}{1.5ex}\kern1pt\rule{.4pt}{1.5ex}\hss\cr\rule{1.5ex}{.4pt}}}}
\begin{document}
Some text \symbolA{} \symbolB{} \symbolC{} and some more text.
\end{document}
```

However, these symbols do not scale properly if used as exponents in math mode.

Answer (score 5):

A possible improvement of Werner's solution. The key point is that it's not necessary to specify some of the dimensions, while keeping the vertical rules as high as capital letters.

Redefine `\reinforcedmain` at will, maybe you can find a better way to draw the circle.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\reinforcedmain}{\raisebox{.3ex}{o}}
\newcommand{\reinforcedrule}{\vrule height\fontcharht\font`\A }
\newcommand{\reinforcedA}{{\normalfont
  \ooalign{\reinforcedmain\cr
           \hss\reinforcedrule\hss
  }%
}}
\newcommand{\reinforcedB}{{\normalfont
  \ooalign{\reinforcedmain\cr
           \hss\reinforcedrule\hss\cr
           \noalign{\hrule}%
  }%
}}
\newcommand{\reinforcedC}{{\normalfont
  \ooalign{\reinforcedmain\cr
           \hss\reinforcedrule\kern.4pt\reinforcedrule\hss\cr
           \noalign{\hrule}%
  }%
}}

\begin{document}
Text \reinforcedA{} \reinforcedB{} \reinforcedC{} end.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following the suggestion of Marc van Dongen, here's a possibly improved version where the thickness of the rules varies according to the type size; the rule thickness is in the `\reinforcedthickness` parameter.

```
\newcommand{\reinforcedmain}{\raisebox{.3ex}{o}}
\newcommand{\reinforcedrule}{%
  \vrule height\fontcharht\font`\A width \reinforcedthickness\relax}
\newcommand{\reinforcedthickness}{0.04em}

\newcommand{\reinforcedA}{{\normalfont
  \ooalign{\reinforcedmain\cr
           \hss\reinforcedrule\hss
  }%
}}
\newcommand{\reinforcedB}{{\normalfont
  \ooalign{\reinforcedmain\cr
           \hss\reinforcedrule\hss\cr
           \noalign{\hrule height\reinforcedthickness}%
  }%
}}
\newcommand{\reinforcedC}{{\normalfont
  \ooalign{\reinforcedmain\cr
           \hss\reinforcedrule\kern\reinforcedthickness\reinforcedrule\hss\cr
           \noalign{\hrule height\reinforcedthickness}%
  }%
}}
```

Comment: I agree this is an improvement but the vertical and horizontal rules don't scale with `tiny`, `small`, and so on. Perhaps this can be fixed by using some thickness and width for the rules that depend on the typesize.

Comment: One could use `width 0.04em` in the definition of `\reinforcedrule` and `\kern0.04em` in the definition of `\reinforcedC`. I'll add this refinement.

Comment: Thanks. I think the OP would need scaling at some stage or another.